# angular-google-maps directive doesn't show markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a hard time figuring out how they in which format this API/directive wants the "coords" option.

Is anyone here who figured it out yet? The problem:

```
<marker coords='{expression}'
icon='{expression}'
    click='{expression}'
    options='{expression}'
    events='{expression}'>
</marker>
```

This is the description of the marker-API. So, **which format should i give the coords**?

> I've tried everything (**array with two numbers, new google.maps.LatLng,
>   just one number**)

My marker isn't shown in my map... who can help?

This is my current HTML:

```
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom" draggable="true">

<marker coords="[52.52000659999999, 13.404953999999975]"></marker>

</google-map>
```

UPDATE: This is my marker:

```
<marker coords="cities.list[0].LatLng"></marker>
```

And the JavaScript Console shows this:

```
scope.cities.list[0].LatLng
Q {d: 52.52000659999999, e: 13.404953999999975, toString: function, b: function, equals: function…}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marker coords are an object having latitude and longitude properties representing the position of this marker e.g.

```
 <marker coords='{"latitude":53.4, "longitude":-0.23}'></marker>
```

see: http://angular-google-maps.org/api

Answer (score 0):

in Angular-Google-Maps,

`map`'s `center` property, `marker`'s `coords` property, `window`'s `coords` property

also is a object which contains latitude & longitude float number